# delete files which are more than one month old using c#

Tags: c#, file, .net-2.0, file-attributes

how to delete files which are more than one  month old using c# script.
i am using framework 2.0..

Comment: Can you give us some more info, delte them? what for? You want to scan your entire pc for files over 1 month old and delete them all ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string path = @"C:\Temp\"; //"

DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[] fileInfos = dirInfo.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
{
    if (fileInfo.LastWriteTime < DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1))
        fileInfo.Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can call `Directory.GetFiles` to find all files in a folder.
You can call `File.GetLastWriteTime` to check when the file was modified.
You can call `File.Delete` to delete a file.